# Firefox stops receiving responses after some HTTP requests (React + Axios, Node.js backend), sends only OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http, axios

As the title says, this only happens in Firefox. After some time the browser only sends OPTIONS requests with no responses, no status, no headers, nothing I can see in the debug console.

[image]

All of this works perfectly under Chrome, Safari and Edge.
I've already set up CORS middleware and headers within NodeJS, so that's likely not the issue. I'm completely lost right now.

[image]

Comment: What is your Firefox version? Btw, is Firefox Developer? 
 https://www.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/developer/

Comment: @Victor Version is 97.0, it's not developer version, just normal Firefox

Comment: Great, @k_krrs. Try turn off HTTPS-Only config in your Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/https-only-prefs.

I guess that problem can be caused by preflighted_ requests. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

Comment: I checked and it's already off sadly, though I did find the answer and I feel stupid, I'll post it as an answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of banging my head against a wall, I realised that an SQL query from the backend ORM wasn't finding one of the pieces of data I need on the frontend (it was `null` in the database), so Firefox instead of simply showing me that it's failing decided to just not show anything.

In short: if you have this problem just **check for errors in your backend**